# ¿What does it means to be a PERSEGUIDO in Argentina?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, significado

The term PERSEGUIDO can mean many things in Argentina. It can be used as a term in justice. Example: The murderer is being PERSEGUIDO by the federal police.

How did the following special meaning of *perseguido* develop in Argentina?

> *No seas perseguido*.

We use this expression when a person interrupts a conversation, making it about him or her.  In this context, "No seas perseguido/perseguida" means *Do not think we're talking about you when it's not like that* or *This isn't about you / It isn't about you*.

Comment: The term "perseguido" means "paranoid" in the sense you used it.

Comment: Check: [Can I answer my own question?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) since this seems the perfect case for a Q&A by the OP (see original version of the question). Someone in for refactoring it?

Answer (score 1):

In Argentina the meaning of ''Perseguido'' is when someone is concern about something.

E.g.: ''No te van a decir nada, no seas perseguido''.

That means: They will not tell you anything, do not be "persecuted".

You can also interpret how: you will be fine, do not think about it.

I hope you understand!

Another example is when you did a test and you know that is correct, but for some reason, you think you will fail. In that case you are being ''Perseguido''

Comment: Do you mean, don't be paranoid, don't act like a "perseguido" (someone who's being persecuted unfairly)?

Comment: Yes, I do. Another example is when you did a test and you know that is correct, but for some reason, you think you will disapprove. In that case you are being ''Perseguido''.

Comment: I think you mean "fail," not "disapprove."  "Disapprove" is, for example, what the worst kind of mother-in-law does about everything about you.

Comment: Yes, i meant that

Comment: Great, Knarf, now you can have some fun learning how to edit a post.  You can add this additional example by clicking where it says "edit" under your post.